# Remix IDE getting error "Please select the folder in the file explorer where the metadata of contract can be found"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I've been following the tutorial in [ethereuembook](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/02intro.asciidoc#creating-the-contract-on-the-blockchain). I created a contract called `faucet.sol` in the browser directory of Remix IDE. The contract compiled successfully. However, when trying to deploy (in both Javascript VM and injected web3 environment with metamask), I'm getting the following error,

```
creation of faucet errored: Please select the folder in the file explorer where the metadata of faucet can be found
```

Not able to figure out how can I generate this metadata and select the folder in file explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the contract open in a tab.

1. Click in "File Explorers" icon (see image below)
2. Click in your contract to open in a tab
3. Click in "Deploy & Run Transactions" icon
4. Click in "Deploy" button

[image]